# RadioButton can be clicked at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

`RadioButton` supposed to be clicked one at a time right?
how come I could click it both?

[image]

here is my mark up:

```
<fieldset style="width: 158px; margin-top: 5%;float:left;margin-left:3%;">
    <legend>Add/Update Products</legend>
    <label>
        Add
       <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" />&nbsp;Update<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" />
    </label>
     <br />
    <label>
        Category:
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox align="middle" ID="txtCategory" runat="server" CssClass="textbox1"></asp:TextBox></label>
    <br />
    <label>
        Type:
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox align="middle" ID="txtType" runat="server" CssClass="textbox1"></asp:TextBox></label>
    <br />
    <label>
        Image:
        <br />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /></label>
    <br />
    <label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFileStatus" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFile" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </label>
    <label>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btnAdd" Height="36px" Width="84px" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
        &nbsp;
   <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btnCancel" Height="36px" Width="84px" />
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

I need to only choose one. But when I tried to click again the same button twice
the mark won't disappear.

Comment: They need the same name.

Comment: You need to put the Radio buttons into a GroupBox to allow only one to be selected.

Comment: You should set the same `GroupName` for both RadioButtons.

Comment: @Doug It did work.`GroupName`is what I used.

Comment: Wow nobody asked if OP googled it before posting! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When only **one selection** is possible from a list of available options you need to set the [`GroupName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx) for both `RadioButtons`. When this property is set, only one `RadioButton` in the specified group can be selected at a time:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="gr1"/>
&nbsp;Update
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="gr1"/>
```