# Why doesn't radio button work?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using radio button inside gridivew. I want to select 1 radio button at a time not multiple. I tried this but not working i.e it disables the only selected one too.

```
protected void btnAward_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvAppliedWorks.Rows) 
        {
            int RowIndex = gr.RowIndex;
            int AppliedWorkID = gvAppliedWorks.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToInt32();
            RadioButton rdbtn = gr.FindControl("btnAward") as RadioButton;

            if (rdbtn.Checked == true) 
            {
                //if(RowIndex )
                rdbtn.Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {           
          Utility.Msg_Error(Master, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking but if I understand correctly you want your `RadioButton` can be clicked at the same time if so check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642334/radiobutton-can-be-clicked-at-the-same-time

Comment: Make sure they all (`radio buttons`) belong to a single group on your form/template/view

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

### **GridView**

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="rbtn1" name="rbtn" GroupName="rgrp" onclick = "RadioCheck(this);" ></asp:RadioButton>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value = '<%#Eval("ID")%>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

### Code for filling gridview from DB

```
        protected void bind()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection string"))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tableName", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataSource = dr;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Finally add this script to avoid multiple selection

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
 function RadioCheck(rb) {
    var gv = document.getElementById("<%=GridView1.ID%>");
    var rbs = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");

    var row = rb.parentNode.parentNode;
    for (var i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++) {
        if (rbs[i].type == "radio") {
            if (rbs[i].checked && rbs[i] != rb) {
                rbs[i].checked = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```